# Is a continuous function integrable in a Jordan measurable subset?

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Is the following statement correct?

> Given a  Jordan measurable subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable in $A$.

Comment: What about $A=\Bbb{R}^n$ and $f=1$?

Comment: I think the OP is interested only for all such bounded Jordan measurable sets.

Comment: @user284331 Sure, but boundedness is important. That's why I left a comment.

Comment: Actually a bounded $f$ is integrable on a bounded Jordan set if and only if $f$ is continuous almost everywhere on that set, this result can be found in William R. Wade, Introduction to Analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, so if I assume that $A$ is also bounded is the statement true?

Comment: It depends, in William R. Wade's definition of Jordan set, it has already assumed to be bounded, anyway, bounded is always significant.

Comment: @user284331 Thanks a lot! Could you give me a suggestion on the reason why the continuity of the function makes it integrable? Is there any theorem on this? I find it difficult to find theorems on integrability of function with multiple variables, so could you suggest me about that?

Comment: You can see Spivak, Michael, Calculus on Manifolds for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The boundary of a Jordan measurable set is a measure zero set. Consider a closed rectangle $R$ that contains the given Jordan measurable set $A$ (boundedness is assumed to be part of the definition of a Jordan measurable set). Define a function $f_{A}$ that is $f$ on $A$, and $0$ outside $A$ in $R$. We show that $f_A$ is integrable. Observe that for points in the interior of A, $f_A$ = $f$ in some open nbd of the points, hence $f_A$ is continuous. For points in $R$ that are outside $\bar{A}$, $f_A$ is the constant $0$ function in some open set in $R-\bar{A}$, and is hence continuous. Therefore the set of discontinuities of $f_A$ is  contained in the boundary of $A$ which has measure zero, which shows $f$ is integrable. I leave it to you to show that int $A \cup  \delta A = \bar{A}.$